# Laravel - vue.js component working locally, but not found in production

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have vue.js components in my app. This is the first time ever receiving this message in the console.

The picture where 3 boxes are shown is the local machine, where it works and shows the users info.

The next picture only show 1 out of 3 boxes, with the "example" component.

[image]

[image]

## Code:

### The component:

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <loading-spinner v-if="!data_is_fetched"></loading-spinner>
        <div v-else-if="data_is_fetched">
            <!-- Modalbox -->
            <div>
                <div v-if="modalbox" @close="modalbox = false">
                    <edit-user-information-modal v-if="modalboxType === 1" @close="modalbox = false" @postSucces="fetchData()"
                         :student="record.user">
                    </edit-user-information-modal>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card box-shadow border-0">
                        <div class="card-header bg-transparent justify-content-between d-flex align-text-center">
                            Min bruger
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <p><span class="font-weight-bold">Navn:</span></p>
                                    <p><span class="font-weight-bold">Fødselsdato:</span></p>
                                    <p><span class="font-weight-bold">Email:</span></p>
                                    <p><span class="font-weight-bold">Telefonnummer:</span></p>
                                    <p><span class="font-weight-bold">Brugertype:</span></p>
                                    <p><span class="font-weight-bold">Vejnavn & husnummer:</span></p>
                                    <p><span class="font-weight-bold">Postnummer og by:</span></p>
                                    <p><span class="font-weight-bold">Land:</span></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <p>
                                        <span v-if="record.user.name">{{ record.user.name }}</span>
                                        <span v-else class="font-italic">Intet navn</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <span v-if="record.user.birthday">{{ record.user.birthday }}</span>
                                        <span v-else class="font-italic">Ingen fødselsdato</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <span v-if="record.user.email">{{ record.user.email }}</span>
                                        <span v-else class="font-italic">Ingen email</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <span v-if="record.user.phone">{{ record.user.phone }}</span>
                                        <span v-else class="font-italic">Intet telefonnummer</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <span v-if="record.user.role_id = 1">Elev</span>
                                        <span v-else-if="record.user.role_id = 2">Kørelærer</span>
                                        <span v-else-if="record.user.role_id = 3">Køreskoleadministrator</span>
                                        <span v-else-if="record.user.role_id = 4">MitKørekort - Support</span>
                                        <span v-else-if="record.user.role_id = 5">MitKørekort - Superbruger</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <span v-if="record.user.address_1">{{ record.user.address_1 }}</span>
                                        <span v-else class="font-italic">Ingen addresse</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <span v-if="record.user.zip_code">{{ record.user.zip_code }}</span>
                                        <span v-else class="font-italic">Intet postnummer</span>
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <span v-if="record.user.country">{{ record.user.country }}</span>
                                        <span v-else class="font-italic">Intet land</span>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="modalbox = true; modalboxType = 1">Rediger</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card box-shadow border-0">
                        <div class="card-header bg-transparent">Ny adgangskode?</div>
                        <div class="card-body text-center">
                            <a class="mt-2 btn btn-primary btn-block" href="/nulstil/kodeord">Nulstil min adgangskode</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import FormMixin from '../../FormMixin.js';

    export default {
        mixins: [ FormMixin ],

        data() {
           return {
               record: {},
               fetchUrl: 'v1/account/fetch',
               data_is_fetched: false,
               modalbox: false,
               modalboxType: 0,
           }
        },

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.fetchData()
        },

        methods: {
            fetchData() {
                axios.get(this.fetchUrl)
                    .then(response => (
                        this.record = response.data
                    ))
                    .finally( this.data_is_fetched = true)
            },
        },

    }

</script>
```

### The component registration

```
// Account
    // Profile page
    Vue.component('page-show-account', require('./pages/account/Show.vue').default);
```

Comment: Your production build likely failed due to having javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you drop your code?

I guess maybe you have a problem with registering the component, maybe you did not type correct path, or etc.

My advice is to read carefully

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: can you try to give a name to your component? name: 'age-show-account', I am not 100 percent but maybe it works.

or maybe you need to follow the global registration

https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Automatic-Global-Registration-of-Base-Components

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that the server had the newest compiled files in "public" and not "public_html".

So there wasn't anything missing or wrong in the code itself, but the server didn't use the correct files.